# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find near by locations (php & Mysql),

```
"SELECT * ,((ACOS(SIN(33.9697897
* PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(33.9697897
* PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS((-118.2468148
-`lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM `gladlashes` HAVING distance<=150 ORDER BY distance ASC";
```

I use above query it run fines on mysql database when we directly insert in sql of Mysql,
But it gives following error when using from PHP script,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(33.9697897
* PI() / 180) *' at line 1
```

Please help me

My Php code is

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$ss="SELECT * ,((ACOS(SIN(33.9697897
    * PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(33.9697897
    * PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS((-118.2468148
    -`lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM `gladlashes` HAVING distance<=150 ORDER BY distance ASC";
     $sql_select=mysql_query($ss,$con) or die(mysql_error());

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_select))
      {
      $result_data[]=$row;
      }

    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$result_data));
```

In db.php only connection is writen

Comment: show the php code you tried to run ?

Comment: I run this query on my db. but I don't have any error. please check it again.

Comment: $ss="SELECT * ,((ACOS(SIN(33.9697897
* PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(33.9697897
* PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS((-118.2468148
-`lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM `gladlashes` HAVING distance<=150 ORDER BY distance ASC";
 $sql_select=mysql_query($ss,$con) or die(mysql_error());
// die();
  //$tot= mysql_num_rows($sql_select);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_select))
  {
  $result_data[]=$row;
  }

echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$result_data));

Comment: yes when we run on db it don't give any error but when we run from php script it gives error.

Comment: Can you give the exact PHP code (edit it into your question) with newlines etc intact?

Comment: I suppose the newlines are the problem. Try removing them and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `33.9697897` is in the query? Can you `var_dump($q1);` (or `var_dump($ss)`, your variables don't line up) for us?

Comment: It working fine on db..but gives error when use from php

Answer (score 1):

Well...

You're not using your `$ss` variable to query the database. You query it using the `$q1` query string...

Change the line:

```
$sql_select=mysql_query($ss,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: sorry while writing on stackoverflow i make that mistake it is correct in my code